# List out of Bounds Visualforce email Template

Tags: visualforce, email-template, controller, salesforce2salesforce

This is driving me a bit insane. When I do a query run with the query editor and give it an id, it returns the values I need but for some reason, I am not getting anything in my email template when I try a send test and merge fields

I am trying to show the owner of the lead in my email template using the component. Can someone please point me to why I am not getting any value.

Template

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Hello" recipientType="Lead" relatedToType="Event">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
  <c:emailcomponent eventID="{!relatedTo.id}"/>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody> 
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Component

```
<apex:component controller="emailCtrl" access="global">
    <apex:attribute type="id" name="eventID" assignTo="{!incomingEventID}" description="parameter to pass event id" />
    <p>{!l.Owner.Name}</p>
</apex:component>
```

Controller

```
public class emailCtrl{
    public Id incomingEventID         {get; set;} 
    public Lead l             {get; set;}

    public leadEmailComponent_Ctrl(){
        Event e =[Select id,whoId, who.Id from Event where id=:incomingEventID][0];
        id leadOwnerID = e.Who.Id;
        l=[Select id, Name, Owner.id, Owner.Name from Lead where id =:leadOwnerID][0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your custom component have the global `access` level? This is required to use it within a Visualforce email template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that it calls the constructor of your controller before to assign your attribute on your component ==> your incomingEventID is null. Better to NOT pass by your constructor and query your lead into your get method. I got this issue before as well.

That should fix your problem :

```
public class emailCtrl{
    public Id incomingEventID         {get; set;} 
    public Lead l             {
            get{
                Event e =[Select id,whoId, who.Id from Event where id=:incomingEventID][0];
                id leadOwnerID = e.Who.Id;
                return [Select id, Name, Owner.id, Owner.Name from Lead where id =:leadOwnerID][0];
            } 
            private set;}

    public leadEmailComponent_Ctrl(){}
}
```

***Note:*** You might have a warning into the email template config because it can not find a record to preview your template. But if you make a test it should work.

Comment: I am into the very same situation and I just did absolutely everything from this chain. But still, the emailtemplate doest NOT populate the owner name. It works ONLY during TEST. I placed a 'send as email' button on event detail page and when I click it, i am opening the template using the javascript. Here is my code. It still fails throwing 'index out of bounds' exception
location.replace('/email/author/emailauthor.jsp?&retURL={!Event.Id}&p2_lkid={!Lead.Id}&template_id=00X17000000QBKp&new_template=1')